# Counting data and inserting manually, date with specific number

Tags: php, mysql

If I press ok button, it just refresh my page, but not appearing errors, what is my error? I already debug it by erasing else at the later part, and still not working..

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
if(isset($_POST['ok']))
{
$udate=date("y-m-d");
$date=date("y-m-d");

$ticket=mysql_query("select count(udate) as ticketcount from tbldate where udate='$udate'",$conn);
if($data=mysql_fetch_array($ticket))
{
$ticketcount=$data['ticketcount'];

if($ticketcount==1)
{
mysql_query("insert into tbldate(udate, date) values('$udate002', '$date')",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<script>alert('Second Ticket of the day!');</script>";
header('Refresh:0;URL=date.php');
}
else if($ticketcount==2)
{
mysql_query("insert into tbldate(udate, date) values('$udate003', '$date')",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<script>alert('Third Ticket of the day!');</script>";
header('Refresh:0;URL=date.php');
}
else if($ticketcount==3)
{
mysql_query("insert into tbldate(udate, date) values('$udate004', '$date')",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<script>alert('Fourth Ticket of the day!');</script>";
header('Refresh:0;URL=date.php');
}
else
{
mysql_query("insert into tbldate(udate, date) values('$udate001', '$date')",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<script>alert('First Ticket of the day!')</script>";
header('Refresh:0;URL=date.php');
}
}
}
else
{
header('Refresh:0;URL=date.php');
}
?>
```

This is my form

```
<form action="date_process.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" id="ok" name="SUBMIT">
Date: <input type='text' name='date' size='25'>
</form>
```

updated. still not working

Comment: You need more code here - where is the 'ok' button? What's loading this page?

Comment: it's editted @Arif_suhail_123 but still no error apearring and not saving into database

Comment: it's updated now, but still not working. thanks

Comment: This is the most thankful conversation ever.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: sir @Fred-ii- still not working. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you didnt have to change this one

```
if(isset($_POST['ok']))
```

But you have to change the button form

Use this

```
<button type="submit" name="ok">Send</button>
```

Instead

```
<input type="submit" id="ok" name="SUBMIT">
```

And it will work :)

Comment: still error, even if(isset($_POST['ok'])) i think its fine, but still error, i did it already. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Khrisna Gunanasurya